Child/childhood child development tag
Should we have tags for issues about childhood/development etc?
will provide linked suitable questions if oyu like

We've got a developmental-psychology tag and a parenting one, I think these cover most of the bases we'll encounter.

I think it is a good question. In some sense child psychology is a subfield of developmental psychology. I remember in undergraduate studies, there were discrete textbooks devoted to child psychology versus developmental psychology. 
And there certainly are different topics that concern the development of children, versus change in adulthood and older adulthood.
I think we briefly had a child-psychology tag, but at some point decided to just go with the developmental-psychology tag.
I guess it relates to a general issue about the best level of generality to have tags.
So at the moment we have:

parenting
aging
developmental
parenting

That said, developmental is a major tag, which might get split in some strange ways if there was a separate child-psychology tag.
So with all that meandering, I'm happy with the status quo of just having a developmental-psychology tag to capture it all, but I don't feel too strongly either way.

Wow, we have two parenting tags? :)

Until quite recently, developmental psychology was concerned with childhood and adolescence only, because it was thought that psychological development ended with the advent of adulthood. Developmental psychology was synonymous with "childhood psychology". Therefore I think that even after the extension of developmental psychology over the life span it still covers the whole of "childhood psychology", with the exception of those aspects that lie within clinical psychology.
